# Check if a particular string or string part exists in a List<string>

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a function where I pass string value that should return me one string if that string or part of string (first 6 characters) exists in a list, if string or string part (first 6 characters) is not exists in list it should return null.

For example if search for:

```
EURUSD- it returns EURUSDf // good since EURUSD exists in list 
EURUSD  it returns EURUSDf // good since EURUSD exists in list
EURUSDf it returns EURUSDf // good since EURUSD exists in list
EURUSDu it returns EURUSDf // fail
EXCEUR is returns null     // good since EXCEUR is not exists in list
```

But what should it return for passed string is:

```
EURUSD- should return EURUSDf or EURUSDu // since EURUSD exists in list
EURUSD  should return EURUSDf or EURUSDu // since EURUSD exists in list
EURUSDf should return EURUSDf // since EURUSDf exists in list
EURUSDu should return EURUSDu // since EURUSDu exists in list
EXCEUR should return null     // since EXCEUR is not exists in list
```

Problem is probably because foreach loop goes through each line and it stops on first match it find. If you check in list it contains `"EURUSDf", "EURUSDu"` EURUSDf is always first so it will take him, it is ok on some cases but it is not if i search for `EURUSDu` strict and this returns me `EURUSDf`.

Since `"EURUSDf", "EURUSDu"` exists in list and i search for `EURUSDu`how to skip to it and return `EURUSDu` or if i search for `EURUSDf` to return `EURUSDf`?

Here is code

```
string symbol = MapSymbol("EURUSDu"); // pass string and get output
Console.WriteLine($"Symbol is {symbol}"); // output

public static string MapSymbol(string symbol)
{
    try
    {
        symbol = symbol.Trim();
        string symbolReturn = "";

        List<string> symbolList = new List<string>() { "AUDCADu", "AUDJPYu", "AUDNZDu", "AUDUSDf", "AUDUSDu", "CADJPYu", "EURAUDu", "EURCADu", "EURCHFu", "EURGBPu", "EURJPYu", "EURNZDu", "EURUSDf", "EURUSDu", "GBPAUDu", "GBPCADu", "GBPCHFu", "GBPJPYu", "GBPNZDu", "GBPUSDf", "GBPUSDu", "GER30u", "HK50u", "JPN225u", "NAS100u", "NZDCADu", "NZDUSDf", "NZDUSDu", "SPX500u", "UK100u", "UKOILu", "US30u", "USDCADf", "USDCADu", "USDCHFf", "USDCHFu", "USDJPYf", "USDJPYu", "USDXu", "USOILu", "XAGUSDf", "XAGUSDfv", "XAGUSDu", "XAUUSDf", "XAUUSDfv", "XAUUSDu", "XINA50u" };

        foreach (var item in symbolList)
        {
            if (item == symbol)
            {
                symbolReturn = item; break;
            }
            else if (item == symbol.Substring(0, Math.Min(symbol.Length, 6)))
            {
                symbolReturn = item; break;
            }
            else if (item.Substring(0, Math.Min(item.Length, 6)) == symbol)
            {
                symbolReturn = item; break;
            }
            else if (item.Substring(0, Math.Min(item.Length, 6)) == symbol.Substring(0, Math.Min(symbol.Length, 6)))
            {
                symbolReturn = item; break;
            }
            else
            {
                symbolReturn = null;
            }
        }
        return symbolReturn;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Exception in maping symbol, {ex.Message}");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Think you need to read [List<T>.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.find?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Find_System_Predicate__0__), and [List<T>.FindAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findall?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_FindAll_System_Predicate__0__).  Don't reinvent the wheel if you don't have to.

Comment: so you basically want a priority for your 3 rules. Would you please post the priorities in a clear and readable manner? like a table?

Comment: @J... if it is homework, they might well have to reinvent it ;)

Comment: is it homework?

Comment: Guys this is not homework and please read what i get returned back from function and please test code first. I don't have any issues if there is only one EURUSD string in list, but when there is 2 or more then this fails.

Comment: @J... homework questions are perfectly fine, as long as he shows effort and asks a narrow enough question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution I can offer is that you extract your tests in a separate collection using the [Func](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-3?view=netframework-4.8) data type, the position will be the priority here. Then you go test rule by test rule and iterate through your collection. If the first rule gives you a positive result, then you stop looking. If not, then you iterate again using the next rule and so on. I hope you get the drift.

```
public static string MapSymbol(string symbol)
{
    try
    {
        symbol = symbol.Trim();
        string symbolReturn = "";

        List<string> symbolList = new List<string>() { "AUDCADu", "AUDJPYu", "AUDNZDu", "AUDUSDf", "AUDUSDu", "CADJPYu", "EURAUDu", "EURCADu", "EURCHFu", "EURGBPu", "EURJPYu", "EURNZDu", "EURUSDf", "EURUSDu", "GBPAUDu", "GBPCADu", "GBPCHFu", "GBPJPYu", "GBPNZDu", "GBPUSDf", "GBPUSDu", "GER30u", "HK50u", "JPN225u", "NAS100u", "NZDCADu", "NZDUSDf", "NZDUSDu", "SPX500u", "UK100u", "UKOILu", "US30u", "USDCADf", "USDCADu", "USDCHFf", "USDCHFu", "USDJPYf", "USDJPYu", "USDXu", "USOILu", "XAGUSDf", "XAGUSDfv", "XAGUSDu", "XAUUSDf", "XAUUSDfv", "XAUUSDu", "XINA50u" };

        // functions can be saved as Func<string, string, bool>
        // that means it takes 2 strings as input parameters and returns a bool
        List<Func<string, string, bool>> TestCases = new List<System.Func<string, string, bool>>()
        {
            (item, sym) => item == sym,
            (item, sym) => item == sym.Substring(0, Math.Min(sym.Length, 6)),
            (item, sym) => item.Substring(0, Math.Min(item.Length, 6)) == sym.Substring(0, Math.Min(sym.Length, 6))
        };

        bool matchFound = false;
        // iteration over each test rules
        foreach (var test in TestCases)
        {
            // iteration ver your collection
            foreach (var item in symbolList)
            {
                // test for a match
                if(test(item, symbol))
                {
                    matchFound = true;
                    symbolReturn = item;
                }
            }

            if (matchFound)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        return matchFound ? symbolReturn : null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Exception in maping symbol, {ex.Message}");
        return null;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try such method:

```
static List<string> symbolList = new List<string>() { ... };

public static string MapSymbol(string symbol)
{
  // we have exact match
  if (symbolList.Contains(symbol)) return symbol;
  // look for first 6 character match
  var sixCharPrefix = symbol.Substring(0, 6);
  // returns first matched string, if not found return default for string, which is null
  return symbolList.FirstOrDefault(s => s.StartsWith(sixCharPrefix));
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is simple solution that works with all cases i tried.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to traverse the list multiple times or use linq, then you could introduce the concept of priority:

```
public static string MapSymbol(string symbol)
{
    try
    {
        symbol = symbol.Trim();
        string symbolReturn = null;
        int priority = 5;

        List<string> symbolList = new List<string>() { "AUDCADu", "AUDJPYu", "AUDNZDu", "AUDUSDf", "AUDUSDu", "CADJPYu", "EURAUDu", "EURCADu", "EURCHFu", "EURGBPu", "EURJPYu", "EURNZDu", "EURUSDf", "EURUSDu", "GBPAUDu", "GBPCADu", "GBPCHFu", "GBPJPYu", "GBPNZDu", "GBPUSDf", "GBPUSDu", "GER30u", "HK50u", "JPN225u", "NAS100u", "NZDCADu", "NZDUSDf", "NZDUSDu", "SPX500u", "UK100u", "UKOILu", "US30u", "USDCADf", "USDCADu", "USDCHFf", "USDCHFu", "USDJPYf", "USDJPYu", "USDXu", "USOILu", "XAGUSDf", "XAGUSDfv", "XAGUSDu", "XAUUSDf", "XAUUSDfv", "XAUUSDu", "XINA50u" };

        foreach (var item in symbolList)
        {
            if (item == symbol)
            {
                symbolReturn = item; 
                break; // best priority so no need to look at the rest of the list
            }
            else if (priority > 2 && item == symbol.Substring(0, Math.Min(symbol.Length, 6)))
            {
                priority = 2;
                symbolReturn = item;
            }
            else if (priority > 3 && item.Substring(0, Math.Min(item.Length, 6)) == symbol)
            {
                priority = 3;
                symbolReturn = item;
            }
            else if (priority > 4 && item.Substring(0, Math.Min(item.Length, 6)) == symbol.Substring(0, Math.Min(symbol.Length, 6)))
            {
                priority = 4;
                symbolReturn = item;
            }
        }

        return symbolReturn;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Exception in maping symbol, {ex.Message}");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works with my original question i asked but i accepted @Michał Turczyn answer since it shorter solution than mine and yours. Voted up :D